# Error running Java cron from command line with Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, cron

This all works when running from eclipse as a standalone application.

My Java main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException, RequestErrorFault, UnexpectedErrorFault, ServerErrorFault {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "webapp" + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + File.separator + "spring" + File.separator + "appServlet" + File.separator + "cron-context.xml");

        CheckStatus checkStatus = context.getBean(CheckStatus.class);


        List<Integer> requestIds = checkStatus.getRequests(); 
        checkStatus.processRequests(requestIds);
    }
```

Output:

```
java -cp /html/myProj/API/target/classes:/html/myProj/API/target/API-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib  com.api.spring.management.CheckStatus
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I have passed in the lib folder on the classpath where all the spring jars exist. I have also tried running this through mvnexec:java but neither seem to work.

Comment: Try with `java -cp "/html/myProj/API/target/classes:/html/myProj/API/target/API-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/*"  com.api.spring.management.CheckStatus`. (note the `/*` at the end)

Comment: That actually helped, but now I get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext"

Comment: This is another error, meaning you are missing the `servlet-api` jar.

Comment: I would suggest building and packaging your application with maven and use some plugin (such as https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)  in order to build a fat jar and avoid all these classpath issues.

Comment: But I still need to call individual java application files within that, as I have multiple crons in there

Comment: For some reason servlet-api jar is the only jar missing from the lib folder. I copied it in manually and it ran just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to this:

> Try with java -cp
>   "/html/myProj/API/target/classes:/html/myProj/API/target/API-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHO‌​T/WEB-INF/lib/*"
>   com.api.spring.management.CheckStatus. (note the /* at the end) – 
>   Tunaki

It also turned out I had one of my dependencies wasn't set to be exported in the war, so after I fixed that it all worked.